# How to run Dot net installer silently though "WixMbaPrereqPackageId"

Tags: wix

i am trying to install the .net version 4.6.1 silently but it is not working.

```
    <WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="NetFx461" />
    <PackageGroup Id="NetFx461">
      <ExePackage DisplayName="Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1" Name=".NET Framework 4.6.1"
                  Id="Netfx461Full"
                  Cache="no"
                  Compressed="yes"
                  Permanent="yes"
                  PerMachine="yes"
                  Vital="yes"
                   InstallCommand=" /q /norestart /ChainingPackage &quot;[WixBundleName]&quot; /log &quot;[NetFx461FullLog].html&quot;"
                  SourceFile="Prerequisites\Dotnet\DotNetFramework_4.6.1.exe"
                   DetectCondition="(Netfx461FullVersion &gt;= &quot;4.6.01055&quot; OR Netfx461x64FullVersion &gt;= &quot;4.6.01055&quot;)">
        <Payload SuppressSignatureVerification="yes" Compressed="yes" Id="DotNetFramework_4.6.1.exe" Name="DotNetFramework_4.6.1.exe" SourceFile="Prerequisites\Dotnet\DotNetFramework_4.6.1.exe" />
     </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
```

i am getting following pop-up still
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zeDr.png)

how to install the Dot net silently without this popup?

Answer (score 0):

That the prerequisite bundle UI. When you click `Accept and Install`, the .NET redistributable will install silently and your bundle UI will be shown.

Comment: Can we install .NET redistributable exe without clicking on Accept and Install button?

Comment: You can run the bundle silently with the `/silent` or `/q` switches.